# turning a string into a MyString object type in java

Tags: java

i am having problem to return a string in my programmer class cause i can't turn it into a MyString(my customized object ) type..how to fix it

```
MyString subString (int start)
  {

    String a="";

    char [] newData=new char[data.length];
    for(int c=0;c<newData.length;c++)
    {
      newData[c]=data[c];
    }
    for(int c=start;c<newData.length;c++)
    {

      a+=newData[c];
      System.out.println(a);
    }


    MyString tempot=new MyString(a);




    return  data ;
  }
```

Comment: show your custom type..

Comment: You do realise you're returning `data` not `tempot`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return `tempot` because that's the return type of your method

Your method signature returns `MyString`

```
MyString subString (int start){
}
```

So you should return a `MyString` object

```
MyString tempot=new MyString(a);

return tempot;
```

**Edit:**

```
public class MyString {
    String text;

    public MyString(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String subString (int start){
        int thisStart = start;
        char [] textArray = text.toCharArray();
        int newCharSize = text.length - start;

        char [] newData=new char[newCharSize];

        for(int c=0;c<newData.length;c++){
            newData[c]=textArray[thisStart];
            thisStart++;
        }

        return newData.toString() ;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return text;
   }
}
```

Here is a test class for your `MyString`

```
public class TestMyString {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String text = "Hello World!"
        MyString myString = new MyString(text);

        String subString = myString.subString(3)
        System.out.println(subString);
        // Output:  "o World!"

        System.out.println(myString);
        // output "Hello, World!"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i know but....but i want to return the string ....how will i be able to turn the string a into MyString object type

Comment: If you just want to return the string, why are you using MyString, why not just return a String in your method signature?

Comment: You turn the `String` into a `MyString` object by doing this `MyString tempot=new MyString(a);`

Comment: i am just making customized string methods .....i'm rewriting built in string methods ....so here in the case of subString() i have to return a string for which i've written the code but here i have to return it in MyString type ...but as u said it to pass it through the MyString object....i did it ...but the problem is that it is just printing the adress of the string ......how can i send the actual string not the adress to print

Comment: Look at my edit.  I think the purpose of this exercise is to implement your own `String` class (MyString)`. So you should put all you `String` methods in your `MyString`.  And when you call it from the `main` method, you create a `MyString` object like this `MyString myString = new MyString(someString)`. Then to get the `subString()` you call it like this `myString.subString(someInt)`.  If you have an exercise to "recreate" an existing class, this would be the way.

Comment: See my edit again. I added a `toString()` override method.  You have to do this if you want to customize your class output.  So when you do this `System.out.println(myString)`, you get the `String` representation your looking for intstead of the "address" you're talking about.  I think this is what you are looking for.